# Flutter And Dart Plugins Aren't Recognized By Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

- Flutter SDK is successfully installed and referenced
  [image]
- Dart is also
  [image]
- I've tried uninstalling/installing them countless times
  [image]

Unfortunately, `flutter doctor` outputs those plugins aren't installed/referenced.

I've also tried others solutions, but nothing changed.

How to fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: try restarting the android studio and then run flutter doctor.

Comment: Installing a plugin forces the android studio for restart already. And I restarted independently too

Comment: do you have multiple Android Studio? Check if the version you are running is 4.1.0.

Comment: No doubts, only one android studio and it's  4.1.0

Comment: did you tried to run a project,i have same problem but i can run and debug project without any problem,Try to run your project or create new one check if it is working@blackkara

Comment: The project is working, and app is running without a problem! But doctor stucked on those issues.

Comment: I don't think this is a big problem,i think this issues shows only in 4.1 the older versions are fine,as long as you can run and debug and create build,then it does't affect the your app,i have app works fine even if it shows this@blackkara

Comment: That's not a problem, but doesn't change existence of the issue.

Comment: Try to switch to the dev channel, the error is because the plugin is not compatible with the new version of Flutter SDK in the stable channel.